# BASIC IF THEN using Like

Tags: oracle, if-statement, sql-like

I am currently trying to write an IF/THEN statement in BASIC but none of the 6 relational Operators seem to help me. I want to compare a variable (srName) and if it contains the letters TS I want the relevant statements to play out.

Just to add the bit of the code below for  anyone that wants to see it. I have currently left LIKE in there to show what I want it to do. I know it won't work as is with that condition.  The only line that is broke is the first one.

```
IF srName LIKE '%TS%' THEN
    status = ChangeSpec(result, 'T')
    return newDate
ELSEIF srName LIKE '%SD%' THEN
    status = ChangeSpec(result, 'F')
    return newDate
ELSE
    return ""
ENDIF
```

As the code is I get an error stating i am missing an ENDIF which I clearly am not.  And the reason i know the problem is specifically with the part

```
LIKE '%xx%'
```

is because when i remove that with a simple

```
IF (srName = TSA245) THEN
```

which for testing I have forced my variable to match then the code works fine

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and you current code

Comment: Added the changes there now! @GMB

Comment: (1) In which database are you running this code: mysql, oracle, sql-server..? Please add the relevant tag to your question. (2) Is this part of a function? A stored procedure? Please show your entire code.

Comment: 1) this is an Oracle database. Tag added now. 2) it is a stored procedure. Can't supply  all the code as a lot of it is business related. In summary srName is a variable string. TS/SD are just a part of a string. newDate is a dates associated to srName. @GMB

Comment: Wait a minute. You are using an Oracle database. Code you posted is written in BASIC (a programming language). Is that correct? **Where** did you execute it? What does Oracle have to do with BASIC? Oracle uses SQL, not BASIC. Your code smells like PL/SQL, but isn't really it (wrong syntax, double quotes, missing semi-colons, ...) so - it probably is BASIC. Therefore, once again: how are Oracle and BASIC related in this particular problem?

Comment: @Littlefoot Oracle doesn't really. It is BASIC that's what I said at the start but was told to add Oracle too. The software pulls from an oracle based database (I do have SQL queries too). But the calculations that display in the software is in BASIC only which is the part i am doing now. There should be  no SQL in my code and only BASIC. Software is LIMS btw.

Comment: If it is BASIC, then enclose all strings in double quotes. Your `LIKE '%TS%'` means just `LIKE` and some comment after it.

Answer (score 0):

OK I have managed to solve it. LIKE won't work in any configuration but instead i used the InStr function like below.  Hope this helps others.

```
IF (InStr(srName, "TSA") = 1) THEN
    status = ChangeSpec(result, 'T')
    return newDate
ELSEIF (InStr(srName, "SDA") = 1) THEN
    status = ChangeSpec(result, 'F')
    return newDate
ELSE
    return ""
ENDIF
```

Note: This works because i know my variable srName will begin with TSA or SDA. If you don't know where in the string it will be use > 0 instead of = 1